# How to force the Outlook rule to be server-side?

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, rules

Using Outlook 2010 with a corporate Exchange Server.

The rule I want to create is this:

> After rule arrives from `Blah@blah.com`
>      and with `Passed` in the subject
>   Move it to the `SuccessBuilds` folder
>      and mark it `Read`.

When I did that, the Outlook marked the rule as Client-Side.  So I removed the part about marking it Read and it became a server side rule.

So I thought, ok, maybe marking an email as read is a client-side only activity.  So I sent myself an email, closed Outlook, opened the email on my iPhone (thus marking it read).  Then I opened the Outlook again and the email was already marked read.  So clearly marking emails read can be a server-side activity.

So why is my rule being shoved client-side?

Comment: "opening the email on my [your] iPhone" may be a client-side activity.  iPhone is a client.  It is not the Windows Outlook client, but it is a client nonetheless.

Comment: I think what the poster is saying is that the server does know the "read status" of a message, so the server _should be_ able to mark a message as read without a client telling it to do so.

Comment: No answer so far explains how to change a client-side rule to be a server-side rule. Is this not possible? This would be much easier than re-creating all my client-side rules on the server.

Comment: Microsoft provides a listing of what actions make a rule Client side: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/server-side-vs-client-only-rules-e1847992-8aa1-4158-8e24-ad043decf1eb

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Does your MS-Exchange server provide web-based access to your eMail?  If so, try logging into that and creating the rule there (and then it will have to be server-side).

Comment: This works but keep in mind that if you create a server side rule in Outlook Web Access (OWA) then you will no longer be able to edit it in Outlook.

Comment: Also when you edit a rule in OWA and add the action mark message as read the rule becomes visible only in OWA and it's removed from Outlook

Comment: @Pete: note that this is true only if the rule is incompatible with the desktop app. A simple "move" or "copy" rule is fine and would still show up. It's when you add the "mark as read" action that it won't be visible.

Answer (score 11):

If you have the destination folder in Personal Folders, it would be in your pst file(located in PC) and the rule will become client-only. But if you place the destination folder in inbox, the folder will be in your Exchange and the server will process your rules.

Answer (score 8):

Being marked as "read" is a client side action not a server action. When you opened the message on your phone it (the client) read it and then told the server to mark it as read.

Comment: that is not true, Server side rule can mark as read

Comment: This worked for me - toggling "mark it as as read" on rules directly affected if the rule was "client-only".

Answer (score -1):

You can using the outlook web app, set up a rule that will mark the mail as read, and it will work as if it truly was server-side. Anyways, it never pops up as unread in my iphone, even if I don't have the web app or outlook open.

Comment: you are basically saying the same thing as @Randolf two years later without adding any new information.